# QGIS: digitized object disappear when filling in attributes

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, digitizing

When digitizing, for example a point, the attribute window opens for you to fill in the pre-defined columns/information. But no point is shown in the map while you do this in QGIS 2.6. It was shown in 2.2 and I wonder if there is a way to have the object shown while the object attribute dialog is open? (same goes for lines and polygons)

Picture below describes the situation where inside the red circle I have added a shape point feature and now prompted to fill out my attributes. The red circle was drawn on the picture only for illustration.

[image: The red circle is drawn for illustration where I just placed a shape point object]

I run a network installation of QGIS 2.6.1, Win7, 32bit.

Comment: You able to provide a screenshot of your QGIS setup?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should confirm that the edited layer is visible(clicked in layers section).You can also check the color set by default by QGIS for new digitized features.
If the two are ok and the issue persists you can first digitize the features then edit their attributes later.
Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to enter my attributes directly after placing object (and I still want to see my newly added point/line/polygon while doing that)

Answer (score 0):

Is the "Show map" at the bottom checked?

[image]

Comment: Yes, the "Show map" is checked? As I understand it, no-one else encounter my problem, so it must be how I have QGIS set up locally?